# split matrix table based on cell match to column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a big tab-separated matrix in a file on Linux:

```
Name    ID  ABC12   ABCD12  ABCD123 ABCD1234
ABC12   123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABC12   123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD12  123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD12  123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD123 123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD123 123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD1234    123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD1234    123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
```

I want to split this matrix into individual files based on matching in 1st column, [it's a large file, cannot count column numbers]

expected output:

### File 1 ;

```
Name    ID  ABC12
ABC12   123456  XX
ABC12   123456  XX
```

### File 2 ;

```
Name    ID  ABCD12
ABCD12  123456  YY
ABCD12  123456  YY
```

### File 3 ;

```
Name    ID  ABCD123
ABCD123 123456  ZZ
ABCD123 123456  ZZ
```

### File 4 ;

```
Name    ID  ABCD1234
ABCD1234    123456  JJ
ABCD1234    123456  JJ
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Complete ***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ len=split($0,a_pos); for(i=1;i<=len;i++) a_keys[a_pos[i]]=i }
     NR>1{ if(!r[$1]++) { fn="file"++c; print "Name\tID\t"$1 > fn } 
           print $1,$2,$(a_keys[$1]) > fn 
     }' OFS='\t' file
```

- `len=split($0,a_pos)` - split the 1st line into array of "keys"(array `a_pos` is indexed with integer numbers)
- `for(i=1;i<=len;i++) a_keys[a_pos[i]]=i` - flipping `a_pos` into array `a_keys` which will be indexed with string keys (for further processing)
- `fn="file"++c` - constructing filename

---

Viewing results:

```
for f in file[0-9]*; do (echo "$f"; cat "$f"; echo); done
```

---

The output (`file1`, `file2`, `file3` and `file4` consecutively):

```
file1
Name    ID  ABC12
ABC12   123456  XX
ABC12   123456  XX

file2
Name    ID  ABCD12
ABCD12  123456  YY
ABCD12  123456  YY

file3
Name    ID  ABCD123
ABCD123 123456  ZZ
ABCD123 123456  ZZ

file4
Name    ID  ABCD1234
ABCD1234    123456  JJ
ABCD1234    123456  JJ
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>1{if ($1!=p){N="file"++C; print "Name\tID\t"$1 >N};
             print $1,$2,$(C+2)>N}{p=$1}' infile.txt
```

Comment: @AFSHIN thanks mate, would be great if outfiles with headers and file names with ABC12.txt ABCD12.txt ABCD123.txt ABCD1234.txt as names

Comment: @devbasic Updated once again and make it shorter. if you need output files same as column1, change `N=$1""++C` from `N="file"++C`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to save the first line as a variable and then print the rest as needed. This, however, requires saving the entire input file into memory:

```awk
#!/bin/gawk -f
{
    if(NR==1){
        header[1]=$1;
        header[2]=$2;
        for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
            header[$i]=i;
        }
    }
    else{
        data[$1][NR]=$2"\t"$(header[$1]);
    }
}
END{
    OFS="\t";
    for(i in data){
        print header[1],header[2],i > i".txt"
        for(k in data[i]){
            print i,data[i][k] >> i".txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Save that script as `foo.awk`, make it executable (`chmod a+x foo.awk`) and run it on your file:

```
foo.awk file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Usage:** `./split_matrix.awk input.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    cnt = 1;
}

NR == 1 { 
    for(i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {
        headers[$i] = i;            
    }   
}
NR > 1 { 
    if( ! file_names[$1]) {
        file_names[$1] = cnt++;
        printf "%s %s %s\n", "Name", "ID", $1 > "file_"file_names[$1];
    }   
    printf "%s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $headers[$1] >> "file_"file_names[$1];
}
```

#### Testing

**input**

```
Name    ID  ABC12   ABCD12  ABCD123 ABCD1234
ABC12   123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABC12   123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD12  123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD12  123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD123 123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD123 123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD1234    123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
ABCD1234    123456  XX  YY  ZZ  JJ
```

**output** (use `tail -n +1 -- file*` for print file name and file contents. I found this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12554776/2913477))

```
==> file_1 <==
Name ID ABC12
ABC12 123456 XX
ABC12 123456 XX

==> file_2 <==
Name ID ABCD12
ABCD12 123456 YY
ABCD12 123456 YY

==> file_3 <==
Name ID ABCD123
ABCD123 123456 ZZ
ABCD123 123456 ZZ

==> file_4 <==
Name ID ABCD1234
ABCD1234 123456 JJ
ABCD1234 123456 JJ
```